# Prove $(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)\ge (ac+bd)^2$ for all $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis

Prove $(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)\ge (ac+bd)^2$ for all $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$.

So $(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2) = a^2c^2+a^2d^2+b^2c^2+b^2d^2$

and $(ac+bd)^2 = a^2c^2+2acbd+b^2d^2$

So the problem is reduced to proving that $a^2d^2+b^2c^2\ge2acbd$ but I am not sure how to show that

Comment: Do you know $x^2 + y^2 \geq 2xy$?

Comment: See also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1739941/verify-that-a2-b2c2-d2-ac-bd2-ad-bc2-for-any-integ).

Comment: $(ad)^2-2(ad)(bc)+(bc)^2=(ad-bc)^2$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By [Lagrange's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_identity)
$$(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=(ac+bd)^2\color{red}{+(ad-bc)^2}.$$

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**: use Cauchy-Schwarz in $\mathbb{R}^2$ on the vectors $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$. This technique should provide a one-line proof of the desired result.

More directly, from what you've already computed, you can observe that
$$
  a^2d^2 - 2abcd + b^2c^2 = (ad - bc)^2 \geq 0
  \text{,}
$$
so $a^2d^2 + b^2c^2 \geq 2abcd$.

Answer (score 5):

Diophantus has already shown that 
$$(a^{2}+b^{2})(c^{2}+d^{2})=(ac+bd)^{2}+(ad-bc)^{2}.$$ This proves the inequality.