# Show that for any reals $a; b; x; y \ge 0, (ax + by)^2 \le (a^2 + b^2)(x^2 + y^2)$. (Hint: Use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.)

Tags: matrices, inequality, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Having a little trouble with this. The Cauchy-Schwatrz inequality for vectors $u$ and $v$ is generally

$$|(u,v)^2|\le (u,u)\cdot(v,v).$$

Then for a two dimensional space its

$$|(u,v)^2|= (\|u\| \|v\|\cos(\theta))^2\le \|u\|^2\|v\|^2.$$

What I did was set two vectors $u$ and $v$ with the values $u=(a,b), v=(x,y).$

Then I used the inequality to plug in the values.

$$||u||=(a^2+b^2),\qquad ||v||=(x^2+y^2),$$

\begin{align*}
\cos(\theta)&= (u\cdot v)/(||u||\cdot||v||)\\
&= (ax+by)/((a^2+b^2)\cdot(x^2+y^2))
\end{align*}

$$((a^2+b^2)\cdot (x^2+y^2)\cdot(ax+by)/((a^2+b^2)\cdot(x^2+y^2)))^2\le (a^2+b^2)^2\cdot(x^2+y^2)^2$$

after canceling becomes $$(ax+by)^2\le(a^2+b^2)^2\cdot(x^2+y^2)^2.$$

How could I get rid of the square on the terms on the right side of the inequality?

Edited: Looks like a duplicate but when I searched it did not come up on SE as the inequality was rearranged in the previous question.

Thanks DcMcMor for the editing.

Comment: Related: [Identical inequality, less restraint](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1925766/prove-a2b2c2d2-ge-acbd2-for-all-a-b-c-d-in-mathbbr).

Comment: Try to format your posts here using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @StubbornAtom sorry about that, dcmcmor beat me to it.