# Proving that an integer $n = 2^{e_2} \cdot 3^{e_3} \cdots$ can be expressed as the sum of two squares iff $e_p$ is even whenever $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, square-numbers, sums-of-squares

This problem is tripping me up big time. So far, this is what I've got (it's not much):

First, prove that if $e_p$ is even whenever $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$, then $n = 2^{e_2} \cdot 3^{e_3} \cdots$ can be expressed as the sum of two squares.

First, we know that an odd prime $p$ is said to be "splitting" if $p$ can be expressed as the sum of two squares. Then, Fermat tells us that $p$ can be expressed as the sum of two squares iff $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

We know that ${e_p}_i$ will be even whenever $p_i \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ in the prime factorization of $n$. From here, I suppose you could split up the primes of different forms in the prime factorization of $n$ (by different forms I mean all primes $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ and all primes $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$). Although, I am not quite sure where I would go with this. Also, have not even considered proving the converse yet. I think I am just one hint away from proving this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Generalise this problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1739941/verify-that-a2-b2c2-d2-ac-bd2-ad-bc2-for-any-integ

Comment: You never define $p$ as the prime that has an exponent.

Comment: @RossMillikan Well I just did so get wrecked kid

Answer (score 1):

Let $n = s^2m$ for some $s, m \in \mathbb{Z}$, where $m$ is [square free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer). Suppose that each prime factor $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ occurs to an even power in the prime factorization of $n$.

Since for each prime factor $p$ of $n$ such that $p \equiv 3\pmod 4, p$ occurs to an even power, $p \nmid m$. Thus each prime $p_0>2$ that divides $m$ satisfies $p_0 \equiv 1\pmod 4$, so by [this property](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/594/fermats-two-square-theorem-how-do-you-prove-that-an-odd-prime-is-the-sum-of-tw), each $p_0>2$ can be written as the sum of two squares. We know that $2$ can be written as the sum of two squares: $2=1^2+1^2$. By [this property](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1739941/verify-that-a2-b2c2-d2-ac-bd2-ad-bc2-for-any-integ), the product of integers that can be written as the sum of two squares, $m$, can also be written as the sum of two squares. Thus $m=x^2+y^2$ for some $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$. We can now express
$$n = s^2\left(x^2+y^2\right)=(s x)^2+(s y)^2,$$
so $n$ is the sum of two squares.

Suppose that $n=x^2+y^2$. If $m=1$, then $n=s^2$, so each prime $p$ in the factorization of $n$ such that $p \equiv 3\pmod 4$ occurs to an even power. Now, assume $m>1$. We will show that for every odd prime $p$ such that $p \mid m, p \equiv 1\pmod 4$. Observe that $x, y$ can be written as follows: $x=d x_1$ and $y=d x_2$, where $x_1, x_2$ are relatively prime and $d=\gcd(x, y)$. Then we have that:
$$\begin{aligned}
n & =d^2\left(x_1^2+x_2^2\right) \\
\frac{n}{d^2} & =x_1^2+x_2^2 \\
\frac{s^2 m}{d^2} & =x_1^2+x_2^2.
\end{aligned}$$

Since $m$ is square free, $d^2 \mid s^2$, with $s^2=t \cdot d^2$ for some $t \in \mathbb{Z}$, so
$$
t m=x_1^2+x_2^2 .
$$
Then, we know that $p \mid m$, so $p \mid t m=x_1^2+x_2^2$. Thus we have the congruence $x_1^2+x_2^2 \equiv 0\pmod p$, so $x_1^2 \equiv-x_2^2\pmod p$. We will show that $p \equiv 1\pmod 4$.

Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $p = 4k + 3$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then notice that $p-1=4 k+2=2(2 k+1)$, so we have:
$$\begin{aligned}
x_1^2 & \equiv-x_2^2\pmod p \\
\left(x_1^2\right)^{2 k+1} & \equiv(-1)^{2k + 1}\left(-x_2^2\right)^{2k + 1}\pmod p \\
x_1^{p - 1} & \equiv-x_2^{p-1}\pmod p.
\end{aligned}
$$
Now, notice first that since $x_1, x_2$ are relatively prime, $p$ cannot divide both $x_1$ and $x_2$. Suppose $p \mid x_1$. Then $p \mid x_1^2$. We know that $p \mid t m$, so $p \mid t m-x_1^2=x_2^2$. Since $p$ is prime, $p \mid x_2$, contradicting $\operatorname{gcd}\left(x_1, x_2\right)=1$. Thus $p \nmid x_1$ and $p \nmid x_2$. Applying [FLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), we have $x_1^{p-1} \equiv x_2^{p-1} \equiv 1\pmod p$, so we get that $1 \equiv - 1\pmod p$, contradicting $p>2$. Thus, $p \equiv 1\pmod 4$.

Answer (score -1):

Taken from @StinkingBishop 's link:
$$(ac-bd)²+(ad+bc)²=(ac)²+(bd)²-2abcd+(ad)²+(bc)²+2abcd$$ $$=a²(c²+d²)+b²(c²+d²)=(a²+b²)(c²+d²)$$
So a product of sums of squares, $(a²+b²)(c²+d²)$ can always itself be written as a sum of squares, $(ac-bd)²+(ad+bc)²$. You know $n$ is a product of factors of the form $2^k$, $p^k$ when $p \equiv_4 1$, and $p^{2k}$ where $p \equiv_4 3$. All of these can be written as a sum of squares, so their product can.